# How to recover forgotten AES-256 password with bruce force?

Tags: aes, brute-force

The password was set on a flash drive using LaCie Private-Public for Windows 10. The password is 12 character long. For each character, I know if it is a number, special character, lower case letter or upper case letter.

It’s possible that I only have one character wrong, but in that case do not know which character is wrong.

Is brute force possibly an option in a case like this?

I have never cracked a password before, though understand some of the concepts.

Thanks much for any advice anyone has!

Comment: Is there some kind of limit on the number of attempts?

Comment: look in to using the tool "cewl." There are ways to do what you're saying, by isolating only a few characters. I don't recall how to do it though.

Comment: What makes you certain that you've only got one character wrong?  Also, are you able to access the cyphertext to do an offline attack, or would this be an online attack which might need to contend with account lockout?

Comment: Thanks! This would be an offline attack. I'm not aware of a limit on a number of attempts but I can double check that with the vendor (LaCie). The reason I think it's possible I only have one character wrong is because I wrote down the password. Maybe I wrote down one character incorrectly. However, as I was learning to use LaCie I change the password several times. Maybe I saved the wrong piece of paper with the password on it. In that case, I know the format of the password because I always used the same format (i.e. lower case as 1st character, number as 2nd character, etc.)

Comment: Thanks! I took a look at cewl, from what I could see it's designed to generate a password word list from a source website. I didn't see anything about isolating a few characters.

Comment: For permutation, try https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=maskprocessor.

Comment: Thanks! Hashcat mask processor looks very promising. It appears to generate the word list to a file. Currently I enter my password into a pop-up window generated by the LaCie Private-Public application that is stored on the flash driver containing my data. I'm speculating that in order to automate the process of trying a list of passwords in a file, that would require the application I'm cracking to support password entry via command line. Is that correct?